# pg_dump: Dump single table and load to new, empty database

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to use `pg_dump` to dump a single table from a database and load it to a new, empty database on another host. The table(s) I want to dump live in specific schemas on the source database, and I can't figure out a `pg_dump` command to either:

- Include a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement for the schema the table lives in
- Strip out all schema info so the table loads to "public".

A simple `pg_dump` command like so:

```
pg_dump postgresql://username:password@host:5432/dbname --format plain --file table_name.sql  --table my_schema.my_table
```

Includes the schema in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but doesn't include a `CREATE SCHEMA` statement, so running the file with `psql` as-is fails with an error of "schema does not exist". I checked the `pg_dump` documentation and didn't see anything obvious to do what I'm looking for, though I tried using the `--create` flag - but that only creates the database, not the specific schema.

I can write a post-processing script to modify the dump file and add the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement, or strip out the schemas, but I'd rather not have to do that if possible - I just want to be able to run the file created with `pg_dump`.

Is this feasible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I thought this might be the case, but wanted to ask anyway in case there was some part of pg_dump I didn't know about that would let me do this. Thanks for your response.